# Should we have regular voting sessions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

Since a lot of posts in this site don't receive their deserving voting (either up or down), should we specifically have a voting session where users are urged to cast their votes for at least half of the answers and questions posted at the end of each week?

I know this and any other site policy are not going to work with the current lack of motivation on the part of the community for positive contribution to the site, however a distinct site feature or policy of weekly voting session can work to motivate the users to get involved more often and elevate the stature of the site.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very bad idea.  Votes are supposed to be organic where people vote on things they're actually reading because they're interested in that topic.

If someone is interested in a topic they know enough to know whether a question is interesting or good or whatever and can vote on it.  But if you make voting a chore that people do just because they have to or should do they'll just end up voting however.

If people aren't interested enough to read posts already and vote on them because they're useful then the problem is that other people are writing boring posts about boring topics not that people aren't voting on them.

Comment: +1 hmmm, you raise a good point! However I thought this feature serve as a provisional measure to foster a voting habit in a community which seems to lack motivation or obligation to participate. But as you rightly pointed out it must be mostly because many users just don't know enough about a topic to evaluate answers and vote accordingly.